# I'm trying to send JavaScript data to my NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm trying to send geolocation data to NodeJS via a POST request but when I console log the data in my NodeJS code it just shows an empty object.

I tested it already with postman and I can receive the data without a problem. I think the problem resides in the client side of my app

```
//**This is in the client Side(pure JS);

async function getWeather(position){

  let coords ={
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    long: position.coords.longitude
  }

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(coords),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "aplication/json"
    }
  };

  let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/weather", options);
  let location = await response.json();
}
```

.

```
//**This is in the server side

  app.post('/weather',(req,res)=>{

    let coords = req.body;
    console.log(coords); //This shows an empty object

    res.sendStatus(200);
  });
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Where is your body parsing middleware?

Comment: Have you looked in your dev tools network tab to see what is actually being sent in the body of your POST request? That will help pin down where the bug is occurring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your client side you can try this code. You can replace the url with your endpoint and try to fetch the result. As shown below, I'm getting the response back in `data` after executing the script.

I hope this helps.

```js
(async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({lat: 10, long: 20})
  });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();

  console.log(content);
})();
```